# Perform tasks periodically with python irc library

Tags: python, twisted, irc

Is there a way to automate periodic tasks: like sending messages to other users or channels, etc. using python **irclib** or [twisted-based youmomdotcom python irc bot](http://eflorenzano.com/blog/post/writing-markov-chain-irc-bot-twisted-and-python/).

Example of **irclib** based irc client:

```
from irc import client
class OurIRCClient(client.SimpleIRCClient):
    def __init__(self):
        client.SimpleIRCClient.__init__(self)

import sys
client = OurIRCClient()

try:
    client.connect("irc.freenode.net", 6667, myUserId)
    print "connected to irc.freenode.net"
except:
    sys.exit(-1)
    "error: coouldn't connect to irc server"
client.connection.join("#django-hotclub")
client.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Glyph pointed out, i've overridden the instance method **connectionMade** of the irc client class and made it use [LoopingCall](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.task.LoopingCall.html).

```
 def connectionMade(self):
        irc.IRCClient.connectionMade(self)
        task.LoopingCall(lambda : (self.msg(counterpartID, "hi there"))).start(5.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the Twisted-based solution, you can simply use a [`LoopingCall`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.task.LoopingCall.html) to schedule whatever periodic method you want to call.

(If you use irclib it's much harder to do this in a way that works properly in all situations, so I will not include that in my answer here.)