# How to cause twisted based irc client to connect through socks proxy?

Tags: python, twisted, irc, socks

I'm using the [markov chain irc bot](http://eflorenzano.com/blog/2008/11/17/writing-markov-chain-irc-bot-twisted-and-python/) based on twisted. Socks proxy may be putty, listening on port 22.
Adding the following code to the above client (at the top of the py file) didn't help:

```
import socks, socket
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5,
    'localhost', 22)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
```

Whereas, doing so solved the problem while using SimpleIRCClient from irclib, however irclib doesn't fit other requirements.

Thanks.

Comment: Wait, it "didn't help" and it "solved the problem"? What "other requirements" do you have?

Comment: For example, periodical tasks. [periodical tasks with irc client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19259857/perform-tasks-periodically-with-python-irc-library) According to that post, twisted based client is better for periodical tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Jean-Paul Calderone. The following code worked for me.

```
from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint 
from txsocksx.client import SOCKS5ClientEndpoint

if __name__ == "__main__":
    chan = "django-hotclub"
    chain_length = 5

    myID = sys.argv[1]
    counterpartID = sys.argv[2]

    puttyEndPoint = TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, '127.0.0.1', 22)
    ircEndpoint = SOCKS5ClientEndpoint('irc.freenode.net', 6667, puttyEndPoint)
    d = ircEndpoint.connect(MomBotFactory('#' + chan, myID, counterpartID, chain_length, chattiness=0.05))
    reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a socks client library - https://github.com/habnabit/txsocksx.